# cant emit serial commands via node js

Tags: node.js, socket.io, arduino, serial-port, raspberry-pi

Hello Guys i'm using socket.io and serialport from nodejs. Now i want to emit commands on the arduino from a raspberry pi which has the server installed. They are connected via serial. When emitting the serial events the arduino just repeats the emitted message and doesnt do anything maybe you guys could help me finding an error.

Here is my Server code:

```
var http = require('http');

var fs = require('fs');
Serialport = require('serialport');
port = '/dev/tty/ACM0';
// Loading the file index.html displayed to the client

 var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

fs.readFile('./index.html', 'utf-8', function(error, content) {

    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});

    res.end(content);

});

});

serial = new Serialport(port, {baudrate: 115200});



port.on('open', function() {
port.write('main screen turn on', function(err) {
if (err) {
  return console.log('Error on write: ', err.message);
}
console.log('message written');
});
});

// open errors will be emitted as an error event 
port.on('error', function(err) {
 console.log('Error: ', err.message);
 })


//Funktion um daten vom Arduino zu empfangen

  serial.on('data', function(chunk){
  readData  =chunk.toString();
  if(readData.indexOf('\n')){
  io.sockets.emit('message',"Arduino sends: "+ readData);
  } });

 // socket.io initialisieren

 var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);


 io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

// WillkommensgruÃŸ
console.log('Client verbunden');
socket.emit('message', 'Willkommen');

// Falls multiuser irgendwann realisiert sein sollte
// wird eine nachricht ausgegeben das ein neuer user beigetreten ist

socket.broadcast.emit('message', 'neuer Client');



// Wenn das message event ausgelÃ¶st wird wird es in der Konsole geloggt

socket.on('message', function (message){
  console.log(message);
    });
socket.on('move', function(message){
    // move
  var message2 = new Buffer(message);
   console.log(message2.toString());
   return serial.write(message2);
     });
socket.on('start', function(message){
  //motor 1
  var message2 = new Buffer("motor 1");
  console.log(message2.toString());
serial.write(message 2, function(err) {
    if (err) {
  return console.log('Error on write: ', err.message);
}
console.log('message written');
});

  });
  socket.on('stop', function(message){
      //stop
  var message2 = new Buffer("stop");
  console.log(message2.toString());
  return serial.write(message2);
            });
  socket.on('poke', function(message){
                //stop
  var message2 = new Buffer("ping");
  console.log(message2.toString());
  return serial.write(message2);
                      });
socket.on('sensoron', function(message){
                                    //stop
var message2 = new Buffer("sensors 1");
console.log(message2.toString());
return serial.write(message2);
                      });
socket.on('sensoroff', function(message){
                                                        //stop
var message2 = new Buffer("sensors 0");
console.log(message2.toString());
return serial.write(message2);
                      });


});



server.listen(8080);
```

I initialised my commands like this on the arduino:

```
cmdAdd("ping", cmdPing); 
cmdAdd("move", cmdMove);
```

Comment: The implication in your question is that the Arduino is not responding correctly, so why show just the server code?  Although this doesn't seem to be exactly a minimal example, so much code is almost impossible to decode. Have you substituted a terminal program for the Arduino and confirmed that your server code works correctly when it receives a correct response?

Comment: Yeah i already connected to the arduino and can use all of my commands.

Comment: So the arduino obeys the command, but the response from it comes out wrong in the server. Have you confirmed that correct response from a terminal program instead of the arduino is seen correctly in the server? Rather than me asking you questions to drag out of you what you have already tried can you describe every relevant bit of debugging you have tried that makes you so sure the fault is in the server?

Comment: So yeah i connect to the arduino via screen and could use all of my commands which are initialised. It must be on the server because when i write the data the arduino doesn't do anything but there seems to be a connection because i get the outprint. The crazy thing is I even get no error when writing but the on data event just sends me back my send data and the arduino isnt doing anything.

Comment: So sending from the server doesn't work, if the arduino doesn't do anytthing. Have you tried connecting a serial terminal instead of the arduino (so the server sends to the terminal program) and checked that there is expected (or any) output from the server?

Comment: I dont have something like a serial terminal. Or I dont understand what you mean.

Comment: A serial terminal program - there is one in the node.js serialport package

Comment: and how should i use it i dont understand your point to be honest

Comment: Hey so i think i know what is wrong. I may have initialised these commands and can use them in a terminal but to use them here i Need to listen for incoming Data on the arduino right?

Comment: Well yes, but I assumed you had tested that already. What I mean about using a terminal program is that you can use it two ways - instead of the server or instead of the Arduino. For the 'instead of the Arduino', If you have two com ports or another PC with a com port you can wire them together and then in the terminal you will see the commands sent by your server. Conversely can should be able to use a serial terminal program on your server PC (with the node stuff not running so the serial port is available) to send commands to Arduino and check its responses.

Comment: yeah so i found the solution. I work with other students together and they delivered the arduino code. They are using a library called cmd.h which only listens to terminal connections. But in my case i write the data directly to the arduino so i need to write my own arduino sketch that reads the string and cuts it into parts.